# Use of gerund vs bare-infinitive: overfilling vs overfill

Tags: word-usage, gerund-vs-infinitive

How do I explain using "overfilling" instead of "overfill" in the following sentence?

> We needed to announce the party just a few days from the date to avoid overfill the salon.

Comment: Overfill here is a noun, you cannot use it without an article ("to avoid AN overfill of the salon"), overfilling a verb on present participle. What may confuse you is that the same ending in -ing is used for gerunds, that are used as noun also. i.e "a tooth filling"

Comment: @choster But *why* is it the grammatical form?

Comment: I thought this sentence could be written two ways: a) We needed to announce the party just a few days from the date to avoid overfill the salon   or    b) We needed to announce the party just a few days from the date to avoid an overfill of the salon.  Is one more correct than the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb *AVOID* can take a noun phrase (a phrase headed by a noun) as a Complement:

- Avoid [the rush].

Many verbs that can take a noun phrase as a Complement cannot take finite clauses as Complements:

- *We wanted to avoid [we did that]. (ungrammatical)

Many verbs that take noun phrases as Complements cannot take *to*-infinitival clauses as Complements:

- *We wanted to avoid [to do that]. (ungrammatical)

However, most verbs that can take phrases headed by nouns as Complements, if we want them to, can also take gerund-participle clauses (-*ing* clauses) as a Complement:

- We wanted to avoid [do**ing** that].

Note that what Complements a verb takes depends on the individual verb.